# AngularJS: Month filter in drop down list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below I m looping for month but always feb month is missing;Please help with same.i want to display last 3 month show display.

```
$scope.months = [];
    var myDate = new Date();
    var previousMonth = new Date(myDate);

    for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
    var mon=myDate.getMonth()-i;
    if(mon<-1){
      mon=mon+12;
    }
    previousMonth.setMonth(mon);
    $scope.prevMonth = $filter('date')(previousMonth, 'MMMM');
    console.log("$scope.prevMonth ",$scope.prevMonth)
    $scope.prevYear = $filter('date')(previousMonth, 'yyyy');
    $scope.months.push({"val":previousMonth.getMonth()+1,"month":$scope.prevMonth});
    console.log($scope.months);
    $scope.years.push($scope.prevYear);

    }
```

Comment: `.getMonth()` method return currentMonth-1 so you need to handle this in your code. like `var mon=(myDate.getMonth()+1)-i;`

Comment: can u show in code..Edit and display..

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**
That is because your day is 29 today and in February, max date is 28. when you try to set month as 1 (Feb) and date as 29 which is already set. It automatically increases the month ;)

For example:

```js
var overMaxDate = new Date('2018-03-29');
    overMaxDate.setMonth(1)
    console.log(overMaxDate.toLocaleDateString());
    
var maxDate = new Date('2018-03-28');
    maxDate.setMonth(1)
    console.log(maxDate.toLocaleDateString());
```

**Solution:**
You can use https://momentjs.com/ library to manipulate date any way you like. Or you can also keep track of days. Good luck!

Comment: so how i can handle this in my current code..help me with same.i m new in this

Comment: I will really encourage using moment library and you can achieve same goal like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/1IWGoRPAq0Z5u28ZCjGe?p=preview